# Python | функия не видит переменную

Tags: python, функции, pygame

мне нужно сделать состояни при которых будут отрисовываться разные вещи, но когда я хочу изменить это состояние принажатии кнопки, то почему функция не видит переменную "state", в которую я хочу сунуть 'MENU'

```
state = 'START'
def handle_state():
    if state == 'START':
        if start_button.draw(screen):
            state = 'MENU'
```

Comment: объявляйте global, чтоб изменять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [**глобальные переменные**](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/faq.html). Чтобы изменять переменную, находящуюся **не внутри** функции, нужно объявить ее как глобальную.

Для этого вначале функции пропишите

```
global название_переменной
```

В вашем коде будет так:

```
state = 'START'
def handle_state():
    global state
    if state == 'START':
        if start_button.draw(screen):
            state = 'MENU'
```